# Scraping data from php file

Tags: php, json, database

I am trying to get the car positions (if I can the cars state (gas, how clean, etc) from this site: https://carsharing.mvg-mobil.de/?ref=separate.

As far as I can tell they get their data from this URL:

https://carsharing.mvg-mobil.de/json/stations.php

Now I am having trouble converting that into usable XML format. I tried bringing it into String form by using

```
JSON.stringify()
```

and go from there but that didn't seem to work. What im having trouble with are the `{` and quotation marks

Comment: `https://carsharing.mvg-mobil.de/json/stations.php` is a JSON file.  It needs to be *decoded* into an object.  Try using PHP's [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) (or JavaScript's `JSON.parse()`).

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` *encodes* an object/array as an JSON string.  That's the wrong direction here.  You *already* have a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since your question is tagged as php, here is a simple code-snippet that will get you a xml-string:

```
<?php
//get json-string
$cars_json = file_get_contents("https://carsharing.mvg-mobil.de/json/stations.php");
//convert json to array
$cars_array = json_decode($cars_json,true);

//creat xml-object and fill recursive
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
array_walk_recursive($cars_array, array ($xml, 'addChild'));

//create xml-string that can be saved
$cars_xmlstring = $xml->asXML();
echo $cars_xmlstring
?>
```

Comment: Pre-processing data with your server as a proxy is a good thing, so Depending how you want to use this data.. PHP would allow for more options